# Can't install pygame on macos

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I'm using vscode and I installed python, I changed my python interpreter to Python 3.1 which I assumed would change the Python version to 3.1 as well? But when I type python --version it still says 2.7.18... And I also installed pygame using "python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user" in my terminal but still when I try to run this any file that imports pygame it says `ImportError: No module named pygame`
Other people have said they have the same problem and maybe I'm missing something but their solutions didn't work for me?

Comment: did you change Python in `Settings` in `VSCode` for your project? Every project can use different version of Python, and `VSCode` will NOT change it when you change Python in system. You have to change it manually in `Settings` for your project.

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Is it feasible to set python3.1 as the default version of Python in the environment variable?